# Programatically Return to iOS App after Opening Maps Application iOS 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, mapkit

I have my App launching the Maps application on iOS6 using something similar to the following:

```
MKPlacemark* place = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate: latlong addressDictionary: nil];
MKMapItem* destination = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark: place];
destination.name = @"Name Here!";
NSArray* items = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: destination, nil];
NSDictionary* options = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                             MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving, 
                             MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey, nil];
[MKMapItem openMapsWithItems: items launchOptions: options];
```

Is there anyway to add a button or somewhow otherwise return to my App once I am in the Maps App? I'd like to return to my App without hitting the iPhone Home button and clicking on my App icon again.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to exit from Map App in IOS 6 i.e. return control back to app requesting directions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15047322/how-to-exit-from-map-app-in-ios-6-i-e-return-control-back-to-app-requesting-dir)

Answer (score 2):

No, since you don't control anything on the Apple Maps app, adding a button there is out of discussion.

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to use `-[MKMapItem URL]` to pass an app-specific scheme (such as `x-com-myapp://launch`) that, if the user taps, sends them back to your app.

Comment: That's pretty interesting. Have you seen it in practice anywhere?